# Why am I getting a permissions error, even though I have the check using permission_handler?

Tags: flutter

The error I'm encountering is as follows:
PathAccessException: Cannot open file, path = '/storage/emulated/0/Download/lista_de_asistencia_12-12-2023.pdf' (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13)

However, I have some lines where I check whether permission is granted or not for the usage. The permission I am requesting is read and write to external storage. I'm attaching the code below:

```
Class reportProvider
Future<String> generateAttendanceDayReportPDF(
      String dateSelectText, BuildContext context) async {
    final permissionProvider =
        Provider.of<PermissionProvider>(context, listen: false);
    await _attendanceProvider.getListAttendance(dateSelectText);
    List<AttendanceViewModel> reportAttendanceDayList =
        _attendanceProvider.attendanceViewModelList;
    String htmlContent = '''
<style>
        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            margin-top: 20px;
        }
        th,
        td {
            border: 1px solid #dddddd;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }
        th {
            background-color: #f2f2f2;
        }
    </style>
    <h1>Reporte diario de asistencias</h1>
    <p>Fecha: $dateSelectText</p>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Numero Trabajador</th>
                <th>Nombre del Trabajador</th>
                <th>Hora de Entrada</th>
                <th>Hora de Salida</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            ${buildTableHTMLAttendanceDay(reportAttendanceDayList)}
        </tbody>
    </table>''';
    final pdf = pdfh.Document();
    final widgets = await pdfh.HTMLToPdf().convert(htmlContent);
    pdf.addPage(
      pdfh.MultiPage(
        maxPages: 200,
        build: (context) {
          return widgets;
        },
      ),
    );

    String fileName = 'lista_de_asistencia_$dateSelectText.pdf';

    final String filePath = await obtainFilePath(fileName);

    File file = File(filePath);

    if (await file.exists()) {
      await file.delete();
    }

    if (permissionProvider.statusPermision) {
      await file.writeAsBytes(await pdf.save()); =>Here it generates the error
    } else {
      return "Permiso denegado";
    }
    // await openFileFromPath(filePath);
    return filePath;
  }

Class PermissionCommon
static Future<bool> checkStoragePermissions(Permission permission) async {
    PermissionStatus status = await permission.status;
    if (status.isGranted) {
      return true;
    } else {
      await permission.request();
      status = await permission.status;
      return status.isGranted;
    }
  }
AndroidManifest.xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
        android:label="control_asistencia_app"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

- Expected a message about the file location and performed a permission check using an 'if' block